# How to enable all apoc related plugins in a remote Neo4j database connection?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have deployed Neo4j version 5.12.0 on Kubernetes using helm charts in an EC2 server. In neo4j desktop (V 1.5.9) I have created a remote database connection. How to enable all apoc related plugins in the YAML file?

When I run a particular Cypher query I'm facing this error:

> Something went wrong: Neo4jError: Unknown function
> 'apoc.map.removeKey' (line 9, column 59 (offset: 490)) [0] "
> attributes: CASE WHEN ecuProps IS NULL THEN {} ELSE
> apoc.map.removeKey(properties(ecuProps), 'name') END"